# JS Method showing undefined, simple example

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs

Perhaps just that friday mind...

Here's my code..

```
  class LoginScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: ''
    };
  }

  onLoginPressed() {
    console.log('hit');
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    console.log(this.state);
    this.onParselUrl('hey');
  }

  onParseUrl(data) {
    console.log('Parse URL hit');
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

This is the section from my React Native app.

I am calling `this.onLoginPressed.bind(this)` and i get the first `hit` in the console.
When i try chain it to second method `onParseUrl` I get errors.

I have tried `this.onParseUrl` and `onParseUrl` and I've tried it with and without params to no availble.

ReactNative is throwing up as...

`this.onParseUrl is not a function. (In 'this.onParseUrl('hey')', 'this.onParseUrl' is undefined)`

Slightly puzzled, i am sure I am missing something basic!

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure `this === ` your component? That's the most common problem with `this` in JS, but I'm not sure if React native does something to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo

```
this.onParselUrl("hey");
```

should be

```
this.onParseUrl("hey");
```

Also, running code after this.setState() is dangerous and should be avoided: setState() triggers a re-render of your component, so the execution of any code after it is not guaranteed.

Comment: In the question, the error message has correct spelling, but I'ld bet it is the typo. The error message type is consistent with the typo. BTW: running code after `this.setState()` is dangerous and should be avoided: `setState()` triggers a re-render of your component, so the execution of any code after it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks guys, perfect! Thanks for the heads up also @wintvelt - Friday night coding not so up to scratch, sure it autocompleted...